# cannot execute .jar file on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I wrote a program and I want it to finally run on my Mac. I exported the program to a .jar file but I can not open it. I get a error.

The IDE that I am using is Eclipse and I work with JavaFX.
I have the newest JDK and SDK installed.

[image]

I tried double click to start the program.

```
java -jar CopyArgumentsEXE.jar
```

I also tried this with the terminal. This did also not work. I get an error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarful CopyArgumentsEXE.jar
```

Comment: while creating jar have you tell / defined which is main class

Comment: refer :https://www.java67.com/2014/04/how-to-make-executable-jar-file-in-Java-Eclipse.html

Comment: I changed the JRE System Library to 1.8. Now it works fine.